# `conda list` yields different version of tensorflow compared to `tf.__version__`

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, miniconda

I am trying to run a python script on g-cloud. The script is seemingly incompatible with tensorflow > 2.3, so I wanted to run it using tensorflow 2.2.
For that, I created a new g-cloud instance, used **miniconda** as an installer and created my environment with
`conda create -n my_env tensorflow=2.2`
Then, I tried to run the program and had to additionally install `tensorflow-addons`, which I did using `conda install -c esri tensorflow-addons`. When I run `conda list -n my_env tensorflow`, I get:

```
tensorflow                2.2.0           mkl_py38h6d3daf0_0 
tensorflow-addons         0.13.0                 py38_1    esri
tensorflow-base           2.2.0           mkl_py38h5059a2d_0 
tensorflow-estimator      2.5.0              pyh7b7c402_0 
tensorflow-gpu            2.5.0
```

However, when I run `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)))"`, I get 2.5.0 as output.
I don't really understand how this is possible, can anyone help me fix that?
I simply want to run my script `example.py` using tensorflow 2.2

Comment: please check your executable location from both interpreters with `sys.executable`, it gives more clarity

Comment: what do you mean with "both interpreters"? For my environment `my_env`, I get `home/usr/miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python`

Comment: for my `base` env., I get `home/usr/miniconda3/bin/python`

Comment: got it, did you check versions of tf in both environments and ensure activating the `my_env` before calling your script

Comment: In my `base` environemnt, I don't have tensorflow installed. In `my_env`, I get 2.5.0 using `tf.__version__`

Comment: Could be you didn't activate your new conda environment: [link](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment)

Comment: More informative is `print(tf.__spec__)` which will tell you where it loads from. Also, `import sys; print(sys.path)` tells you where the `sites` module is searching.

Comment: Issue might be because of `conda install -c esri tensorflow-addons`, Tensorflow-addons pulling latest stable tensorflow version i.e., 2.5.0. I tested if i use `pip install tensorflow-addons` , it wont changing the existing Tensorflow version. Follow like `pip install tensorflow==2.2` and `pip install tensorflow-addons`. Thanks!

Comment: Any luck? I have the exact same problem. On top of that, my `tf.__spec__` is pointing outside of the conda environment